# Making trial version of client-server application in Java

Tags: java, spring, swing, rmi, trial

I need to know how to make a trial version(e.g 30 days trial) of a client-server application which is implemented using Spring RMI(server side) and Java Swing(client side). 
I'm thinking of doing this in client side by checking current date against first login date. But it might be hackable easily. What are the best options available to do this in a reliable manner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have client-side configuration, add couple of new keys with the date when the client is first launched. People usually won't look into the application configuration for expiration dates.

And, choose the key that doesn't say that it is related to licensing and encrypt your value if possible.

If one key is tampered, you can use the other key to check whether it is tampered or not and block the access.

Comment: what happens if user change the system date? then date calculation will go wrong and it will break the logic.

Comment: If you don't want the user to set the date to "Day 1" of your trial, you have to store 2 values. The Date when the Client is First Launched, and another Date when the Client is recently launched. Second one will be updated upon close of application everytime. So, when the application detects that the Date Recently launched is in Future upon Startup - the user has changed the Date and can block access.

Comment: ok thanks. really appreciate your help.i will use this method if i do this in the client side. Do you have any idea about doing this in server side?

Comment: Check whether the clientKey file is present in USER HOME Directory in Client Machine.
If not found, ask for a clientKey from server and create a new file - good if it can be a hidden file.
Use the clientKey to get remaining days from server.
Upon uninstall, don't delete the clientKey.

Comment: ok. what if end user delete client key? isn't it breach the rule? any solution to that?

Comment: Making it hidden can give some protection. But, if user deletes it. We have to build a mechanism in such a that, clientKey generated for a particular client is always same in the server. For example, usage of MAC Address or Processor ID.

Comment: As you said, i might have to use client specific id(eg. MAC address) to do that. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

A better and safer solution would be to implement it on the server side.

You can make the client request for a token the first time it runs, and keep track of the token on the server. This has a drawback though,i.e. If someone deletes or reinstalls, you will never know.

You can also send a request for token with some identifying characteristics, i.e. MAC address. So that you will know if the client is making duplicate requests.

Even better, instead of tokens, keep track of the MAC addresses.

Comment: You can change the MAC address as shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_spoofing).

Comment: I know, but thats too much trouble a regular user would go to, and depends on whether he/she knows how this trial works. usually users would just look in registry, config and data files or do a reinstall.

Comment: @galuano1 end user will get the control of both server and client sides. so in that case end user can change server side configs and breach to the system. how can i avoid this?